# How to add new document in an embedded document in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a document that stores employee's name and his salary details. The document stores salary details of each month. Note that the field 'Employee_Salary' is not an array. This is my document.

```
{
    "_id" : 5.0000000000000000,
    "Employee_Name" : "John Karrl",    
    "Employee_Salary" : {    
        "April-2015" : { 
            "actual_salary" : 300,
            "bonus" : 0,
            "penalty" : 0,
            "bonus_pen_detail" : "NA",
            "month_paid" : "April",
            "year_paid" : 2015,
            "total_amount_paid" : 300
        }
   }
}
```

Now I want to update this document to insert or add new salary details of the next month, which is May-2015. I have tried using '$push' command but it does not work and gives me the following error.

'The field 'Employee_Salary' must be an array but is of type Object in document {_id: 5.0}'.

Answer (score 1):

**`$push`** can only be applied to array elements. Since `Employee_Salary` is an object you must perform a **`$set`** operation as shown below:

```
db.employee.update(
  {_id: 5.0},
  {$set: {
    'Employee_Salary.May-2015': {
       "actual_salary" : 300,
       "bonus" : 0,
       "penalty" : 0,
       "bonus_pen_detail" : "NA",
       "month_paid" : "May",
       "year_paid" : 2015,
       "total_amount_paid" : 300
     }
   }}
)
```